# WebSocket SSL Issue in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, websocket

I am suddenly getting the following error message when trying to connect to an "wss" WebSocket connection string in Chrome that is not happening in Firefox:

> Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_OBSOLETE_VERSION

My current version of Chrome is: Version 81.0.4044.34 (Official Build) beta (64-bit).

I'm guessing this is due to an update since I was able to connect to the same WebSocket connection string recently and the SSL certificate is the same one I have been using for a while and is valid when I use Firefox.

I have started looking around for documentation on this issue but haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome is [deprecating support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/12/chrome-72-deps-rems).  I modified the code for my WebSocket server by enabling support for TLS 1.2 and that fixed the issue.

Comment: The solution is going to differ depending on what you're using for your Websocket server.

I'm using Fleck (C#) in this case, so I had to add a line like this:

server.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls;